# Removing lines from files with a specific extension

Tags: bash, find, sed

The task is as follows: From all `*.h` and `*.cpp` files, delete lines beginning with `/`.

Removing from the current directory (or from the specified one) works well, and if there is a subdirectory in the directory it does not work. Here:

```
find . -iname '*.h' | sed -i '' '/\//d' *.h
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code there is no real connection between the `find` and the `sed` since you tell `sed` to process the `*.h` files in the current directory and nothing else.

The proper way to have `sed` process all the files found by `find` would be:

```
find . -iname '*.h' -exec sed -i -e '/\//d' {} +
```

If you want to process both `.h` and `.cpp` in one go you can use a logical expression in the  parameters of `find`:

```
find . \( -iname '*.h' -o -iname '*.cpp' \) -exec sed -i -e '/\//d' {} +
```

If there is a reasonable number of file to process (combined length of all names/path under 2MB) you can also use `bash` advanted file pattern abd brace expansion:

```
shopt -s globstar   ## enables "**" matching of directories

sed -i -e '/\//d' **/*.{cpp,h}
```

Comment: Do not tell me how the found files can be checked whether they are available for writing and reading?

Comment: You can add the -readable or -writable flags in `find` to match just the files that have these properties.

Comment: Do not prompt syntax? or where can I read about it? otherwise I can’t find

Comment: See `man find`...